# \phantom doesn't seem to work in matplotlib+latex

Tags: matplotlib, latex

`$\phantom{1}$` is a built-in latex command that gives you the whitespace equivalent of the character `1`.

This seems to crash matplotlib. How can I get the equivalent whitespace of the character `1` in matplotlib text?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possibilities

- try to use `\hphantom` --> horizontal phantom
- quick & dirty: `\,` creates half an empty space ...

Still looking for an explanation...

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some further info? I just tested it on a Jupyter Notebook and it works fine for me. However, with `plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False` (default) I get an error when using `phantom{}`. You can also check [this page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html) of the matplotlib documentation.

Example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

fig, (ax0) = plt.subplots(ncols=1, figsize=(7, 4))

ax0.set_aspect(1)
ax0.plot(np.arange(10))
ax0.set_xlabel(r'$abcd \\ abcd \\ a\phantom{b}cd$')
```